# What's the difference between a load balancer and target group in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm following along a course and I don't really get the difference between an aws load balancer and an aws target group. The course kinda talks about them interchangeably. Does an aws target group include an aws load balancer? What's the theoretical and practical difference?

Answer (score 0):

In AWS, a load balancer is an actual server (or cluster of servers) managed entirely by Amazon that accepts incoming traffic and routes the traffic across multiple backend servers, thus distributing the load.

A target group is simply a list of target servers that the load balancer should distribute the load to.

You configure the load balancer by telling it to send all traffic that matches a certain pattern (like all traffic that comes in on a certain port, or all traffic that is for a certain domain name) to a specific target group.

Answer (score 0):

**Load Balancer** - AWS thing..

**Target Group** - your thing.

Target group is collection of your own servers ( one or more than one server)..

Load balancer help to distribute incoming traffic (API Request etc.) to these different target groups based on rules and listeners.

You need to assign DNS/domain name to load balancer, all incoming traffic first comes to this then it distribute to target groups servers..